# Android studio 3, annotation processors must be explicitly declared now

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I updated my Android studio to 3.0 & starting get this error:

```
annotation processors must be explicitly declared now 
-parceler-0.2.15.jar(org.parceler:parceler:0.2.15)
```

My build.gradle contains the dependency :

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.parceler:parceler:0.2.15'
}
```

How to get rid of this error now with Android Studio 3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each annotation library also needs an annotation processor. In most cases, these are bundled into the main dependency though it can be a second dependency in this case.

So you use the `annotationProcessor` keyword:

```
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:0.2.15'
```

This is in addition to compiling, don't remove that dependency.

Comment: Why Android Studio requires that? It looks like going to a less smart way of building project.

Comment: You're going to have to ask the developers for that, it just works like it. It is harder than a single dependency though, but that's how it works now